# Cypher query in Neo4j browser keeps processing without any result/error/info

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to run some benchmark tests using Neo4j and Cypher queries. My current dataset sizes are 1GB and 3GB. While I have completed the queries on the 1GB dataset, my current query against the 3GB dataset seems to be "executing", but it's been at the same stage for about 30 minutes now. The spinner just keeps spinning on and on.

The same query took only **13068.25 ms** (average from 10 executions) against the 1GB dataset. It seems unlikely that it would take more than 30 minutes against a dataset of 3GB size (I still have 10GB and 30GB dataset sizes to test against).

Even though there was no error thrown while the query was/is executing, I went in the settings (Neo4j Desktop > Manage > Settings) and made sure there was enough memory available. The default size allocated was 512 mb -

```
# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size.
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512m
```

I stopped the query execution, changed these values to 2g (2GB) first and then 4g (4GB) the next time and re-executed the same query. But each time the spinner just keeps spinning -

[image]

My dataset has just 8 entity types and I have indices setup on `id` property of all the entity types. The query I'm executing uses the `id` field to lookup the records with the given values (ex: start Person with a given ID value). After uploading the 3GB dataset, the total size on disk was about 6GB.

I tried to use the "Monitor the system" option to see if I could find any relevant/useful information there, but I couldn't figure out if there was a problem, based on the provided stats (screenshot below) -

[image]

Unless the query *is* executing normally and 30-40 minutes would be the expected query execution time, I'm not really sure what's wrong or what to fix. I think if it had to timeout, it would have probably done so by now.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show your query please. Have you got some indexes ? Maybe you need to set a explicit size to PageCache to avoid faults.

Comment: Can you give the `EXPLAIN` of your queries ?

Comment: We can't know for sure where you are getting burned without the [EXPLAIN](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of your query. That will tell us what the Cypher Planner is thinking of doing, and how expensive it thinks it will be.

As for your Cypher, depending on how long it is, know that cost will grow multiplicatively  by the average match of each variable. (friend -> post looks like it could have an exceptionally high growth rate, and you have more that is unseen) So it could also help if we could see the full Cypher.

Comment: Also, try with just match the start person, and keep rerunning, adding one more path step each time. That should show you where the growth is exploding in your Cypher.